How to disable animation after SetActive(true) in Unity?
I have an animated UI obj (A button) that plays the animation (is switching sprites, between sprite1 and sprite2) after a certain condition, after the button is pressed the sprite of the button changes to sprite3 but when I'm setting active the button to false SetActive(false) and reenable to  SetActive(true) with code the animation start's playing although I expect the button to stay the sprite3. How don't let the Animation play after SetActive(true)?
My Code:
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI; 

public class ChangeClaim : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] 
    private Animator Switch;

    [SerializeField] 
    private Image ClaimBut;

    [SerializeField] 
    private Sprite ButSprite;

    // Start is called before the first frame updateprivate 
    void Update()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Compl1") == 1)
        {
            ClaimBut.sprite = ButSprite;
        }

        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Complete1") == 1)
        {
            playSwitch();
        }
    }

    public void playSwitch()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Compl1") == 0)
        {
            Switch.SetTrigger("Start");
        }
    }

    public void StopSwitch()
    {
        Switch.SetTrigger("Stop");
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Compl1", 1);
    }
}


In general don't fetch player prefs continuously in Update ... and then you could just have another flag / prefs for whether you already played the animation before

Add another animation state with no animation and set it as the default. So when you set active and deactive your button, the button image will not changed because the animation state on default state (with empty animation).


I allready have it like this. On pc it work's but, if i build the project and open this on phone it doesn't work(    I realy don't understand whats the problem

explain what problems occur on the mobile phone. is the problem the same as before?

Yes, it's the same problem as before ....(
Like on pc in UnityEditor it works as it should work, but if I build the app and open it at the phone the animation is still playing after  SetActive(false), SetActive(true).
